# Java Linkedhashmap equals method custom implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, equals, linkedhashmap

I am trying to implement my own LinkedHashMap using chaining strategy for deal with collisions. Below code snippet shows what I have tried so far.

*`CustomLinkedHashMap`*

```
public class CustomLinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private Entry<K, V>[] table;
    private int capacity = 4;
    private Entry<K, V> header;
    private Entry<K, V> last;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CustomLinkedHashMap() {
        table = new Entry[capacity];
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (!(that instanceof CustomLinkedHashMap)) {
            return false;
        }

        CustomLinkedHashMap<K, V> other = (CustomLinkedHashMap<K, V>) that;

        // if lists are empty
        if (header == null) {
            return other.header == null;
        }

        if (!header.equals(other.header)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Just one element
        if (header == last) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!header.equals(other.last)) {
            return false;
        }

        Entry<K, V> thisNode = header;
        Entry<K, V> otherNode = other.header;

        while (thisNode.next != last) {
            thisNode = thisNode.next;
            otherNode = otherNode.next;
            if (!(thisNode.equals(otherNode))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void put(K newKey, V data) {
        if (newKey == null)
            return;    //nulls not allowed

        int hash = hash(newKey);

        Entry<K, V> newEntry = new Entry<K, V>(newKey, data, null);
        maintainOrderAfterInsert(newEntry);
        if (table[hash] == null) {
            table[hash] = newEntry;
        } else {
            Entry<K, V> previous = null;
            Entry<K, V> current = table[hash];
            while (current != null) { // reached to the last entry of bucket.
                if (current.key.equals(newKey)) {
                    if (previous == null) {  //node has to be insert on first of bucket.
                        newEntry.next = current.next;
                        table[hash] = newEntry;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        newEntry.next = current.next;
                        previous.next = newEntry;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = newEntry;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return header == null;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (table != null && capacity > 0) {
            header = null;
            last = null;
            capacity = 0;
        }

    }

    public void printMap() {

        Entry<K, V> currentEntry = header;
        while (currentEntry != null) {
            System.out.print("{" + currentEntry.key + "=" + currentEntry.value + "}" + " ");
            currentEntry = currentEntry.after;
        }
    }

    private int hash(K key) {
        return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % capacity;
    }


    static class Entry<K, V> {
        K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K, V> next;
        Entry<K, V> before, after;

        public Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K, V> next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            if (object == this)
                return true;
            if (object instanceof Entry) {
                Entry<K, V> e = (Entry<K, V>) object;
                if (Objects.equals(key, e.key) && Objects.equals(value, e.value)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

`CustomLinkedHashMap` class Full implementation [here](https://codeshare.io/5Xx4KE).

As for my implementation when I try `equals` method it always returns me `false`.

```
 CustomLinkedHashMap<Integer, String> lhm = new CustomLinkedHashMap<>();
 lhm.put(13, "John");
 lhm.put(3, "Holmes");
 lhm.put(19, "Jenifer");

 CustomLinkedHashMap<Integer, String> lhm2 = new CustomLinkedHashMap<>();
 lhm2.put(13, "John");
 lhm2.put(3, "Holmes");
 lhm2.put(19, "Jenifer");

System.out.println(lhm.equals(lhm2)); // Returns true when using java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Comment: I haven't looked at LinkedHashMap's internals, but there's a good chance it compares `hashCode` instead of uses `equals`

Comment: Why? Are you planning to compare these maps to each other?

Comment: Why do you have this statement in your code? What is it supposed to do? `if (!header.equals(other.last)) { return false; }`?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I have no idea why even trying to implement custom hashmap which is already exists in java collection api. Unfortunately this is for an assignment. :(

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Otherwise it gives me a NullPointerException at `if (!(thisNode.equals(otherNode))) { return false; }`. Inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `equals` for `CustomLinkedHashMap` is way too complicated. All you really need is to check the entries (and their ordering):

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object thatObject) {
    if (!(thatObject instanceof CustomLinkedHashMap)) {
        return false;
    }
    CustomLinkedHashMap<?,?> thatMap =
        (CustomLinkedHashMap<?,?>) thatObject;
    return Arrays.equals(this.table, thatMap.table);
}
```

You also need a solid implementation for `Entry`, which checks the key and value against another:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object thatObject) {
    if (!(thatObject instanceof Entry)) {
        return false;
    }
    Entry<?,?> thatEntry = (Entry<?,?>) thatObject;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.key, thatEntry.key)) {
         return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(this.value, thatEntry.value));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by  `return Objects.equals(this.items, thatMap.items);`  items here ?  `Entry<K, V>[]` ?

Comment: Then it should be `return Arrays.equals(this.table, thatMap.table);` instead of  `return Objects.equals(this.items, thatMap.items);` isn't it ?

Comment: Oops, yes, that’s what I meant! :-)